# Does EMF depend on distance between electrodes in a battery?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields

E.m.f of a cell is defined as work done to carry a unit charge from cathode to anode in internal circuit.

Should not work done increase with distance between distance between electrodes, and thus causing higher e.m.f?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"E.m.f of a cell is defined as work done to carry a unit charge from cathode to anode in internal circuit." You need to insert the words "at very low speed of charge-carriers", in order that *resistive* forces are negligible. But the work done against *electrostatic* forces (due to the charges that build up on the electrodes) as a charge moves from cathode to anode is independent of the separation of the electrodes. This is because the potentials of the electrodes are controlled by the specific chemical reactions that occur at these electrodes and therefore the potential difference between them is independent of the geometry.

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but my book explicitly gives a formula for emf, namely $E=F_b*d/q$ where $F_b$ is the battery force and $d$ is separation between the electrodes. Is this wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, but I don't think it's very helpful. If we have cells with the electrodes and electrolyte *made of the same materials* then the emfs are the same, independent of the linear dimensions of the cells. But $F_b$ would not be the same. Indeed the only reason why it seems that the emf is proportional to $d$ is because we've defined $F_b$ to make it so!

Comment: That clears it up!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're confusing EMF (Electromotive force) with an *actual force*. It is not a force in the newtonian sense, so if you presume that there's some "$\mathcal{E}\cdot\vec{d}$" term that would make sense, that's **not** the case!

EMF is an abstraction for dealing with models of power sources, where the mechanism in the power source is imperfect, but approaches the voltage, $\mathcal{E}$.

To that, $\mathcal{E}$ is a voltage, and so the energy difference is $W_{\text{a}\rightarrow\text{b}}=U_\text{a}-U_\text{b}=q(V_\text{a} -V_\text{b})=qV_\text{ab}$.

Taking ground as zero, so $U=qV_\text{b}=0\implies$ zero potential. The above becomes $$W_{\text{a}\rightarrow\text{b}}=U_\text{a}=qV_\text{a}=q\mathcal{E}$$ which as you can plainly see, does not depend on distance!